# ERROR TypeError: this.product.filter is not a function using Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

I have this function:

```
  public product: Product[] = [];

getProductTName(productTypeId: string) {
        const [filteredProdType] = this.product.filter(pt => pt.product_type_id === productTypeId);
        if (typeof filteredProdType !== 'undefined' && productTypeId === filteredProdType.product_type_id) {
            return filteredProdType.product_type_name;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

In this function I get this error `ERROR TypeError: this.product.filter is not a function` when `product` is empty.

Please, can you ask me any idea, how can I modify the code to not display this error?

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. Filter function exists even on an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a check if this.product is empty or null

```
if(this.product && this.product.length > 0){
 const [filteredProdType] = this.product.filter(pt => pt.product_type_id === productTypeId);
        if (typeof filteredProdType !== 'undefined' && productTypeId === filteredProdType.product_type_id) {
            return filteredProdType.product_type_name;
        } else {
            return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question, since `filter` function exists even on an empty array, and OPs array is initialized to `[]`